# synchronizing distributed offline archives with large files on external drives

Tags: hard-drive, backup, sync, cloud

I have a number of media files (let's say 500 files of 500 MB each, although some are much smaller and some are bigger) that I cannot store on my computer, because the hard drive is too small, so I want to store them on an external drive.

I could just move everything to single drive, but that has the risk to lose everything in a drive crash. So there need to be multiple drives that are synced to each other. The syncing should keep the drives interchangeable, adding one file to one drive should add it to the other drive and deleting one file on one drive should delete it on the other, no matter which one is the one and which one is the other, because I sometimes use multiple computers that are each connected to their own external drive, and I do not want carry some kind of master drive between the computers. So the sync tool needs to keep a history of the meta data of the files that records which files are new and which files were deleted. It should also track renaming, so it does not copy a renamed file in full, as compressed media files are much more likely to be renamed than modified.

The history could also make the backups more reliable, if it has a hash for each file, it could check if the file is still intact or was corrupted by disk problems. And I could look up when the file was added or last changed more reliable than the file system timestamp.

Now I am looking for such a sync tool. (atm I am only using linux, but perhaps I use another OS one day?)

Some tools that do not fit, but get close:

- rsync: It does not keep a history.
- unison: It  keeps  history, but it is on the syncing computer and not with the data. If I sync them on a new computer, it would need to rescan everything. And it uses  pairwise databases, if there are n mirrors on m computers, it would keep m n² histories (or just  m n with a star topology, but then it needs a master drive again). Also the database does not seem to be designed for long term usage, a newer unison version might get a new database format, which then needs to rescan everything and I cannot look up in 10 years when I added which file anymore.
- source control, git, hg, svn, gut, boar: The files are too big to keep a history of everything. Also I have important and unimportant files in the collection, when I run out of space, I rather  delete the unimportant files permanently than buying a larger drive.
- bup, git annex: they remove the files from the file system to store them in their own git based file system. That makes it hard to access them and I prefer a solution that keeps the files as they are and just adds the meta data needed to track the changes.
- git-media: seems mostly made to get around git's file size limitation
- dropbox google drive: are not offline
- owncloud: That seems to be based on a always running central server rather than a bunch of equal hard drives.
- syncthing: it seems to run permanently and sync everything immediately between computers. I want to do the syncing locally, occasionally, as in connect both external drives to the same computer and sync them then once a month
- sparkleshare: seems not be made for big files

Comment: Multiple external drives on multiple devices and active syncing are counter intuitive.  I say use a single master always on repository on some legacy hardware, then us something like resilio sync to push and pull the files.  But this does not create redundancy per se because if you mess up or have a glitch, you can easily lose data.  You still need a SEPARATE backup that gets synced one-way.  Businesses use the 3-2-1- rule as a typical MINIMUM.

Comment: I do not use it often enough to justify dedicated hardware for that. Like once a week on average. It should prevent most glitches with the history. Like Git. You do not have to fear to accidentally corrupt a Git repository. (the sync tool could move deleted files in a thrash folder to allow undoing of the last sync). I could give a drive to my mother in another state, but then I could only sync to that one once a year.

Comment: FreeFileSync, Resilio Sync

Comment: FreeFileSync at least stores the change-tracking database  in the right folder, but it does not store hashes of all files to detect corruption. Resilio seems to be made for permanent background syncing between devices rather than occasional syncing between drives.